# Confused with legacy knockout code. Can't tell if it's commented out or not

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Straight forward am I not new to knockout (some experience with ko 3.5) or html.
I'm working on a project (ko 2.1.0) with a lot of legacy code and I am seeing a lot of code like this:

```
        <!-- ko if: displayLoading -->
    <img class="loader icon-align-center" src="~/Content/img/loader.gif" />
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Is this open and closing knockout tags commented out, or are they taking effect?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: It's the if binding without container element:  https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html (at the end of this page). :-)

Comment: It's called [*"containerless control flow syntax"*](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html#note-using-if-and-ifnot-without-a-container-element)

Comment: I pointed out the fact that @Mohamed does seem new to knockout because the question he asked is the very basic use case of knockout itself and this got deleted, I'm not really sure why but I can guess, although I still think my point is valid as it was to bring it to the attention of the OP that maybe he'd consider taking another look at their basic tutorial..